# Emulate USB joystick with Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is possible to simulate an USB joystick with Cocoa? In the image, the USB Joystick creates a `J1_LEFT` key. It's possible with Cocoa?

Even if it's not simple I'll appreciate if there's a solution.

EDIT:
I found [**DDHidLib**](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2007/03/19/ddhidlib_10/). It's a really nice class, but unfortunately it's from 2008 (but really fits in what I want). If someone have some code (to help me simulating a USB joystick) with this class I'll appreciate.
[image: Example 01]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you looking to simulate a joystick button press, or translate a real joystick button press into a keyboard keypress?

Comment: @PeterHosey I want to simulate a joystick button press. I want to create the "J1_LEFT" key as in the image. It's a little difficult to understand.

Comment: http://www.libsdl.org is, as I know, often used to play with such things.

Comment: @DigiMonk I've been exploring it and doesn't looks like it is going to do the job. Anyway, thanks for the help. :)